# 404 not found Error in Magento Connect Manager

Tags: 404

[image]I want to use magento connect to install a Extension. I am receiving a 404 Cms page when i try to open it.

```
I tried to
```

1. delete the files from var/cache
2. Change permission of Directory /downloader/ set to 755 and file downloader/index.php set to 644. This method works for me .

Answer (score 1):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....